# Find the limit of the sequence $(4^n)/((2n)!)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How to find 
$$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{4^n}{(2n)!}$$
Can I use l'Hopital's rule?

Comment: The limit is 0, so its $\liminf$ = ?

Comment: You can't use l'hospital rule, since $n$ is an integer. However, Stirling's approximation may help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is one way.  Call the term $a_n$.  Then
$$a_n=\frac4{1\times2}\frac4{3\times4}\frac4{5\times6}\cdots\frac4{(2n-1)(2n)}\ .$$
Now it is easy to see that every term except the first is less than $\frac12$, so
$$0<a_n<\frac2{2^{n-1}}\ .$$
The RHS clearly has limit $0$, so by the pinching theorem (squeeze theorem, sandwich theorem)
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0\ .$$

Answer (score 5):

I don't see an application of l'hopital's rule here but using [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) you can deduce that the limit is zero.

If you don't want to use any advanced results like Stirling, you can always go for an elementary proof like the following

$$\frac{4^n}{(2n)!} \leq \frac{4^n}{(n+1)(n+2)...(2n)} \leq \frac{4^n}{(n+1)^n} $$

for $ n \geq 4$ we have  $$ \frac{4^n}{(2n)!} \leq \frac{4^n}{(n+1)^n} \leq (\frac{4}{5})^n $$  and then by taking the limit we find $0$.

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{4^n}{(2n)!} = \cosh(2)$$
hence the limit is trivially zero.

Comment: How did you calculate the sum?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD: from the Taylor series of $\cosh x$, $$\cosh x = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to do it, if you really want to use Hopital (which I don't recommend) consider

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac {4^x}{\Gamma(2x+1)}$$

Now you can use Hopital! :-P

Suppose the above limit exists (call it $l$) and use hopital to find that

$$l = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac {4^x}{\Gamma(2x+1)} = \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac {4^x}{\Gamma(2x+1)} \cdot \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln 4}{2\psi(2x+1)} = l \cdot 0 = 0$$ and hence $l = 0$ . (here $\psi$ is the digamma function, and we know that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \psi(x) = \infty$. Also $\Gamma'(x) = \Gamma(x) \psi(x)$  )

Now since if the limit exists it must be the same on any subsequence. So set $x = n \in \mathbb N$ and the limit will be $0$. But setting $x = n$ you find

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4^n}{\Gamma(2n+1)} = \frac{4^n}{(2n)!} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Let , $a_n=\frac{4^n}{(2n)!}$. Then  , $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{4}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}\to 0 \text{ as } n\to \infty.$$

So, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using AM GM inequality, $$\dfrac{2n}a\ge\dfrac{2n-r}a+\dfrac ra\ge2\sqrt{\dfrac{2n-r}a\cdot\dfrac ra}$$

$$\iff\dfrac{a^2}{(2n-r)r}\le\left(\dfrac an\right)^2$$

Set $r=1,2,\cdots, n$